# Ubuntu 19.04 - Bluetooth device not found during scan (OBD2-ELM327 Bluetooth Adapter)

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

So I'm trying to establish a connection between my laptop and the OBD2 Bluetooth Adapter connected to my car and I'm a bit puzzled. My laptop (which is running Ubuntu 19.04) finds bluetooth devices such as phones or smartwatches but is unable to find my obd2 bluetooth adapter. Meanwhile my phone has no problem finding the adapter and pairing with it. So far I've tried to find it with the GUI's bluetooth settings and bluetoothctl. We are talking about a cheap, generic adapter from China but so far I never had problems with it.

`sudo service bluetooth status` returns the following in case that is helpful:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-09-29 17:35:07 CEST; 28min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1023 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 3.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1023 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 29 17:35:06 Lenovo-Y50-70 bluetoothd[1023]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Sep 29 17:35:07 Lenovo-Y50-70 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Sep 29 17:35:07 Lenovo-Y50-70 bluetoothd[1023]: Starting SDP server
Sep 29 17:35:07 Lenovo-Y50-70 bluetoothd[1023]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Sep 29 17:35:07 Lenovo-Y50-70 bluetoothd[1023]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Sep 29 17:35:08 Lenovo-Y50-70 bluetoothd[1023]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Sep 29 17:35:20 Lenovo-Y50-70 bluetoothd[1023]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.419 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep 29 17:35:20 Lenovo-Y50-70 bluetoothd[1023]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.419 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep 29 17:35:20 Lenovo-Y50-70 bluetoothd[1023]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Sep 29 17:35:50 Lenovo-Y50-70 bluetoothd[1023]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

I am confused by the few lines that say rfkill is blocking something, because `rfkill list` tells me bluetooth is not blocked.

Is there anything else I can try? Thanks in advance to anyone providing help.

Update: After waiting way longer than what seems right two "Unknown devices" show up, one as disconnected, one as not set up, in Ubuntus bluetooth setting, but they are grayed out so I cannot interact with them in any way.