# Blueman-Manager Bluetooth Adapter not found after update

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, bluetooth, parrot-os

I'm currently running Parrot OS and it was working normally, but recently my USB Bluetooth adapter stopped working (it was working yesterday). Since I'm using the default config and haven't changed or installed anything recently to cause this, I suspect it was a recent OS upgrade, since that's the only thing I've done to cause this.

#### Basic info:

`uname -a`:

```
Linux parrot 5.14.0-2parrot1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.14.6-2parrot1 (2021-09-25) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
[Redacted item]
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0b05:190e ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ASUS USB-BT500
[Redacted item]
[Redacted item]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0b05:190e ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ASUS USB-BT500` being the USB Bluetooth adapter that recently stopped working

`hciconfig`:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:84 acl:0 sco:0 events:8 errors:0
    TX bytes:24 acl:0 sco:0 commands:8 errors:0
```

`hcitool dev`:

```
Devices:
```

`rfkill list`:

```
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`ls /dev/hci*`:

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/hci*': No such file or directory
```

`python --version`:

```
Python 3.9.2
```

#### What I've done so far:

- I've tried rebooting my system, of course, both within the OS and by physically removing power from the motherboard.
- I've tried moving the adapter between USB ports and re-seating the adapter.
- I've tried restarting the Bluetooth service
- I've tried reloading the kernel module.

#### Sources I've already found, that didn't seem to help:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working
- https://dev.to/campbelljones74/common-bluetooth-problems-in-ubuntu-and-how-to-fix-them-18b5
- [Bluetooth adapter not detected on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1310775/bluetooth-adapter-not-detected-on-linux)
- [Ubuntu 19.04 - Bluetooth device not found during scan (OBD2-ELM327 Bluetooth Adapter)](https://superuser.com/questions/1487469/ubuntu-19-04-bluetooth-device-not-found-during-scan-obd2-elm327-bluetooth-ada)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104351/blueman-no-adapters-found
- https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-bluetooth-adapter-is-not-detected.34124/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104351/blueman-no-adapters-found
- https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/451
- https://linuxhint.com/restart-bluetooth-ubuntu/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608116/bluetooth-wont-turn-on-on-ubuntu-20-04